# There are $6$ digits containing $1$ and $0$, only problem is that $0$'s can't be next to each other

Tags: probability, combinations

Imagine this: There are $6$ digits which can contain either $1$ or $0$. For example: $100110$
Only problem is that $0$'s can't be next to each other. For example, $101101$ is fine.
How many combinations are there that is a no-no and how many combinations that are fine?

Comment: Let $a_n$ be the number of fine combinations ending in $0$, and $b_n$ be the number of fine combinations ending in $1$.  Write down formulas for $a_{n+1},b_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_n,b_n$.

Comment: Twenty-one combinations are fine.  Counting should do the trick.

Comment: Hey tfk, can you elaborate a bit more? I am not very good with formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's follow tkf's answer.

Let $a_n$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ ending in $1$ and $b_n$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ ending in $0$. Suppose my sequence ends in $1$. Then I could add either a $0$ or a $1$. However, if my sequence ends in $0$, I can only add a $1$. So

$$a_{n+1} = a_n + b_n,$$
$$b_{n+1} = a_n.$$
Now if we know $a_1 = 1$, $b_1 = 1$, let's determine $a_6$. We have

$$a_2 = 2, b_2 = 1, a_3 = 3, b_3 = 2, a_4 = 5, b_4 = 3, a_5 = 8, b_5=5, a_6 = 13, b_6=8.$$

Here's a question: Can you tell me what $a_n$ and $b_n$ are for any $n$?

Regardless, the total number of admissable sequences will be $a_6 + b_6 = 21$. The total number of sequences will be $2^6$ (why?) so the total number of nonadmissable sequences will be $2^6 - 21 = 43$.

Here's another way to think about it: Let
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a(1) & b(1) \\ a(1) & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then
$$ A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} a(1) + b(1) \\ a(1) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a(2) \\ b(2) \end{pmatrix}. $$

By inducting, we see

$$A^{n-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a(n) \\ b(n) \end{pmatrix}.$$
Let $\|(a,b)^T\| = a + b.$ Then

$$\|A^{n-1} \cdot (1,1)^T\| = \text{ total number of admissable sequences}.$$